# HierarchyID C ADO

Tags: c++, mfc, sql-server-2008-r2, ado

I have an MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a table containing a `HierarchyID` column.  I'm using C++(MFC) and ADO.

When I read the root record of the hierarchy, it's `HierarchyId` value, when retrieved via `ADO`, is a `VARIANT` containing an empty `SAFEARRAY` (UI1 with 0 elements).

When I try to pass this same `VARIANT` back as a parameter to an SQL function, I get an error.

SQL Server function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [MaintApp].[fnFindPersHier] ( @hHierId hierarchyid )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM PersHier
    WHERE hHierId = @hHierId
)
```

How do I create a `VARIANT` containing the equivalent of HierarchyID.GetRoot() so that I can pass it to this function?

Comment: What type of value does HierarchyID.GetRoot() return?

Comment: HierarchyID.GetRoot() returns a VARIANT containing an empty SAFEARRAY (UI1 with 0 elements)

Comment: If it returns a VARIANT, why did you ask how to convert it to a VARIANT? Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: I asked how do I create a VARIANT containing the equivalent of HierarchyID.GetRoot() so that I can pass it to this function? ADO returns HierarchyID values as binary, so I'm asking what is the binary representation of the value of the SQL Server HierarchyID.GetRoot()?